# Material-UI Grid: Can I apply the background color to only cells, and not the empty spaces outside them?

Tags: css, material-ui

I'm trying to create a grid system with a gradient background color. However, the background color also applies to the empty spaces not taken up by grid cells. I want just the grid cells to share this gradient. Is there any way to do this?
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWedu.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You should set a linear background color for your container and set `background: 'inherit'` for your grid item. Inside your grid item, you should use an image with a no background color.

Try this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    background:
      "linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(34,193,195,1) 0%, rgba(253,187,45,1) 100%)"
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    background: "inherit"
  }
}));

export default function AutoGrid() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <img
              height="100px"
              alt="cat"
              src="http://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/584c3c8a1fc21103bb375ba7.png"
            />
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <img
              height="100px"
              alt="cat"
              src="http://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/584c3c8a1fc21103bb375ba7.png"
            />
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <img
              height="100px"
              alt="cat"
              src="http://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/584c3c8a1fc21103bb375ba7.png"
            />
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <img
              height="100px"
              alt="cat"
              src="http://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/584c3c8a1fc21103bb375ba7.png"
            />
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <img
              height="100px"
              alt="cat"
              src="http://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/584c3c8a1fc21103bb375ba7.png"
            />
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Select with checkboxes and sub headers]

Comment: This does not turn the space outside the tiles to white - what I wanted was something like this: https://imgur.com/a/KEATqdx.